# upload photo to Facebook from flash mobile project using as3

Tags: android, facebook, actionscript-3, flash, photo-upload

i am currently developing android application...
i want to upload photo to facebook from my application...

i am using this.. but it is to share the link... what i want is to upload photo and message only which user can see whole message in the post.
Please help me!!!

Below is my code:

```
var appId:String = appId;
        var messageTitle:String =title;
        var messageUrl:String = link;
        var messageDescript:String = message;
        var appThumb:String = imageUrl;
        var redirectUrl:String = "https://www.facebook.com";

        var URLString:String = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id="+appId+"&link="+messageUrl+
                                "&description="+messageDescript+"&name="+messageTitle+"&picture="+appThumb+
                                "&redirect_uri="+redirectUrl;

        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(URLString);

        try{navigateToURL(req,"_blank"); }

        catch (e:Error){ trace(">> ERROR <<", e.message); }
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use a AS3 API for Facebook, it could make your job easier ([API AS3 FB](https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/))

After FB inizialize and fb login u can use this code

```
var params:Object = { url:url, message:description, fileName:url_or_filename};
Facebook.api('me/photos', Function_callback , params , 'POST');
```

But if u want only use Graph URL u need this method `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos`.
You can see more informations and parameters about POST photos [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/)

Hope This help